# Is there a way to insert a published paper url link in Github readme as a reference material?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages, github-api, github-for-windows

I want to insert the URL link of a published paper in my Github ReadMe file. What are the possible ways to achieve this? Please, can anyone provide a suggestion? I want a situation where I can just click on the URL link and it will immediately direct me to the paper.

Your kind suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this simple steps to insert url to your github ReadMe file.

1.) Write a short text in a square bracket to represent the clickable link.

2.) Write the URL next to it in parenthesis.

kindly follow the example below

[Click here to read the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08620.pdf)

[image]